# Using Gatsby Background with Multiple Images

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am trying to use `gatsby-background-image` with multiple images but I can't get it to work.

I have the following

```
const {backgroundImages} = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      backgroundImages: allFile(
        filter: {extension: {regex: "/(png)/"}, relativeDirectory: {eq: "slider"}}
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            base
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData(width: 10, quality: 10, webpOptions: {quality: 70})
              
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
```

```
const image = getImage(backgroundImages.edges[0].node.childImageSharp)
const bg = convertToBgImage(image)
```

This is how I am using the BackgroundImage component

```
<BackgroundImage Tag="section" {...bg} preserveStackingContext className={styles.bgImg}>
    {props.children}
</BackgroundImage>
```

I've tried accessing the gatsbyImageData property of the object but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting the first image (node) in:

```
const image = getImage(backgroundImages.edges[0].node.childImageSharp)
```

If you use a loop with:

```
const images = [];

backgroundImages.edges.map(backgroundImage => images.push(backgroundImage.node.childImageSharp)
```

Once you've stored your nodes, you just need to print it like:

```
images.map(image => {
let bg= convertToBgImage(image);

return <BackgroundImage Tag="section" {...bg} preserveStackingContext className={styles.bgImg}>
    {props.children}
</BackgroundImage>
})
```